# I have to work with an asp.net application, and could use a good glossary/dictionairy of asp.net terms

Tags: asp.net

I am a coldfusion programmer, and have to understand, diagnose, and document an asp.net applicaiton.

But the terms are very hard to translate into laymen's terms, at least for me, so if any good links to a glossary of terms, would be really helpful.

Thank You.

Comment: Could you list a couple of the terms you're referring to? (ASP.NET has a ton).

Comment: Here are a few: integration classes, resulting assembly, assembly references,  integration methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your best bet would be to take a couple hours out of your coding schedule to sit down with the [Introduction to ASP.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywdtth2f%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) section of MSDN.

Some upfront reading about the architecture will clarify a lot of terms and save you tons of time down the road.

Oh - there is also [this .Net Glossary page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470362.aspx), which does contain some terms specific to ASP.Net.